# Why is it not recommended to manipulate Qt UI controls in threads?

Tags: c++, qt5

I haven't encountered any exceptions when manipulating UI controls in threads myself, but some people have advised me not to do so. I'm very puzzled.

How should it be implemented then? Should I use signals and slots?
Who can help me clarify?

Comment: Re. `"How should it be implemented then? Should I use signals and slots?"`: indeed, you've answered your own question :-)

Comment: as with any non-threadsafe code, if you get "lucky" it might just work, however your luck will eventually run out and bad things will happen. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html

Comment: Because libraries are not threadsafe unless they specify they are. (making libraries threadsafe comes with costs for single threaded use). You should find a way to send messages or command to your UI mainthread from background threads (I don't know how Qt does that but it should be in)

Comment: what did some people say when you asked them? Seriously, advice along the line "dont do X" is only worth as much as it comes with explaining why, without it is called [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Comment: It is wrong to assume that you will encounter exceptions or any other kind of explicit errors when manipulating objects from different threads without proper synchronization.  You'll get Undefined Behavior which means anything can happen. SA [Undefined behavior can result in time travel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)

Comment: All running code is in some thread or another - manipulating QObjects of any kind must only be done from that object's _owning_ thread (for UI widgets, that's the UI thread; for other Qt objects it may well be a different thread).  For inter-thread method invocations, Signals and Slots are provided for exactly this purpose.